# Placing output of 'each' into a BS3 grid. (Ruby+)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

Hard to explain - I've done this a few times this way:

```
var foo = 0

<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<% @cards.each do |card| %> # Could be 30K or 500K in it. Doesn't matter.
foo++

if foo % 3 == 0
then </div></div><div class="row"><div class ="col-md-6">
else </div><div class="col-md-6"
```

~ish - I've done it differently numerous times but same logic. Basically every 3 times I need to close the initial 'row' div, and re-open it. Other-wise it'll just keep generating col-md-6 which will cause a straight line down of divs.

Is there a cleaner way to do this?

The last time I did research on it, I came across the concept of 'templating' which led me to use

```
!(i % 3) && ($lastRow = $("<div>", { "class": "row" }).appendTo('.test'));
        $lastRow.append($deckClone);
      }
```

Both processes worked but I'm curious on a better way - ESP more 'Ruby'ish way.
BS3 is my 'go-to' for front-end but if I can do it with simple CSS/HTML that works also.

Comment: I find your wording a bit confusing, but I suggest you check out [in_groups_of](http://apidock.com/rails/Array/in_groups_of) on the apidock...i think it should solve your problem

Comment: @MageeWorld Thanks for the recommendation! I'll go take a look. I think it might be exactly what I want.

Comment: I expect it is - (it was when I needed to solve what I think  is a similar issue) I would have tried to write out the code as an answer but couldn't get it clear in my mind from your examples